# Need multiple file upload file script for mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, upload, insert

Can anyone refer me to an upload script (jquery, javascript, or php) for posting multiple photo images to an already existing record?

The record will already be created.  I need the client to upload multiple files to a corresponding record.  One record may have up to 10 photos.

I need a script that will post to my records in mySQL.

Any feedback and input would be appreciative.

Thank you.

Erik

Comment: Create One, Tell us where you get stuck Or hire me :P, if you need the script.

Comment: you can try N number of file uploaders available on net , and tailor them as per your need

Comment: @Erik, Sure, Give me your IM ;)

Answer (score 0):

[swfupload.org](http://swfupload.org) is pretty cool, but per the comments, you'll need to do some work.